# Oops andTainted G for DVB adaptor load

Tags: 14.04, drivers, kernel

Can anyone advise on Oops and Tainted fail please? 
Running the 3.16.0-4-amd64 kernel and loaded media_build from v4L and supporting applications. But both of 1. Hauppage WinTV Nova TD500 and 2. PCTV 292e fail to load with Oops and Tainted comments followed by stack trace dump to log. /dev/dvb/...is not created either.
Only TD500 fail included in below log for clarity. 
Have reapplied all apps and booting without the device hardware all OS loads fine. 
Both working perfectly and continuously for almost 2 years on older kernel (2013) so not hardware. All firmwares deployed fine and driver load ok.

I see no note of this problem anywhere else.
Before I blast it all away and start again can anyone suggest what it maybe to avoid repeating the mistake?

```
'May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    5.915054] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    5.976960] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2040, idProduct=8400
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    5.984968] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    5.992290] usb 2-1: Product: WinTV Nova-DT
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    5.998524] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Hauppauge
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    6.004632] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 4035120147
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    6.376060] tsc: Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 1862.098 MHz
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    6.692076] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [    6.869108] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=9254

May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.085906] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.098974] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.119568] leds_ss4200: no LED devices found
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.150143] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.217753] iTCO_vendor_support: vendor-support=0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.218313] iTCO_wdt: Intel TCO WatchDog Timer Driver v1.11
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.218349] iTCO_wdt: unable to reset NO_REBOOT flag, device disabled by hardware/BIOS
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.291929] Adding 6155260k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:6155260k SSFS
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   12.311691] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   13.189391] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   13.320840] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-TD-500 (84xxx)' in cold state, will try to load a firmware
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   13.328646] usb 2-1: firmware: direct-loading firmware dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   13.335781] dvb-usb: downloading firmware from file 'dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw'
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   13.548240] dib0700: firmware started successfully.
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.060212] dvb-usb: found a 'Hauppauge Nova-TD-500 (84xxx)' in warm state.
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.069479] dvb-usb: will pass the complete MPEG2 transport stream to the software demuxer.
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.077218] DVB: registering new adapter (Hauppauge Nova-TD-500 (84xxx))
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.086638] usb 2-1: media controller created
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] PGD 0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] Modules linked in: dvb_usb_dib0700(O+) dib9000(O) dib7000m(O) dib0090(O) dib0070(O) dib3000mc(O) dibx000_common(O) dvb_usb(O) dvb_core(O) rc_core(O) media(O) iTCO_wdt iTCO_vendor_support dcdbas joydev lpc_ich mfd_core coretemp kvm serio_raw i2c_i801 rng_core i3000_edac shpchp edac_core floppy(+) evdev processor thermal_sys loop nf_conntrack_pptp nf_conntrack_proto_gre nf_conntrack fuse parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic btrfs xor raid6_pq sr_mod cdrom sg hid_generic usbhid hid sd_mod crc_t10dif crct10dif_generic crct10dif_common ata_generic psmouse ata_piix radeon libata scsi_mod i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_kms_helper drm i2c_core tg3 ptp pps_core libphy uhci_hcd button ehci_pci ehci_hcd usbcore usb_common
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] CPU: 0 PID: 237 Comm: systemd-udevd Tainted: G           O  3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-1
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] Hardware name: Dell Inc.                 PowerEdge SC440              /0YH299, BIOS 1.3.0  03/28/2007
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] task: ffff88007c184390 ti: ffff88007c2e0000 task.ti: ffff88007c2e0000
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81513080>]  [<ffffffff81513080>] __mutex_lock_slowpath+0xb0/0x1c0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] RSP: 0018:ffff88007c2e38c0  EFLAGS: 00010286
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff880079f96478 RCX: 0000000000000000
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff88007c1843f8 RDI: ffff880079f9647c
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] RBP: ffff88007c2e3910 R08: 000000000000005d R09: ffff88007b3f1068
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] R10: 0000000000000013 R11: 0000000000000014 R12: ffff880079f9647c
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] R13: ffff88007c184390 R14: 00000000ffffffff R15: ffff880079f96480
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] FS:  00007fb9f6703880(0000) GS:ffff88007fc00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 000000008005003b
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 00000000366fe000 CR4: 00000000000007f0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] Stack:
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  ffff880079f96480 0000000000000000 ffff880079f963f0 ffff88007b3f1068
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  ffff880079f96408 ffff880079f96478 ffff880079f96000 ffff880079f96478
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  ffffffffa06787a0 00000000000000ff ffff880079f963f0 ffffffff815131ab
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] Call Trace:
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff815131ab>] ? mutex_lock+0x1b/0x2a
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa064015e>] ? media_device_register_entity+0x7e/0x200 [media]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff812b60a2>] ? vsnprintf+0x3d2/0x5c0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff812b9c36>] ? kvasprintf+0x66/0x80
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff812b9c8e>] ? kasprintf+0x3e/0x40
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa0665760>] ? dvb_create_tsout_entity+0xd0/0x160 [dvb_core]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa0665d59>] ? dvb_register_device+0x569/0x7d0 [dvb_core]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa06675c8>] ? dvb_dmxdev_init+0xf8/0x140 [dvb_core]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa068da5c>] ? dvb_usb_adapter_dvb_init+0x1bc/0x2d0 [dvb_usb]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa068cba6>] ? dvb_usb_device_init+0x5b6/0x890 [dvb_usb]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff8151319e>] ? mutex_lock+0xe/0x2a
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa06b7993>] ? dib0700_probe+0x63/0x110 [dvb_usb_dib0700]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa00190dc>] ? usb_probe_interface+0x1cc/0x320 [usbcore]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff813a4e7d>] ? driver_probe_device+0x9d/0x3d0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff813a527b>] ? __driver_attach+0x8b/0x90
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff813a51f0>] ? __device_attach+0x40/0x40
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff813a2f7b>] ? bus_for_each_dev+0x5b/0x90
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff813a4510>] ? bus_add_driver+0x180/0x250
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff813a59cb>] ? driver_register+0x5b/0xe0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa00179cc>] ? usb_register_driver+0x7c/0x150 [usbcore]
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffffa06dc000>] ? 0xffffffffa06dbfff
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff8100213c>] ? do_one_initcall+0xcc/0x200
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff810db34d>] ? load_module+0x210d/0x26f0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff810d6fb0>] ? store_uevent+0x40/0x40
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff810dba8d>] ? SyS_finit_module+0x7d/0xa0
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  [<ffffffff81514a0d>] ? system_call_fast_compare_end+0x10/0x15
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] Code: 00 8b 03 85 c0 78 09 31 c0 87 03 83 f8 01 74 72 48 8b 43 10 4c 8d 7b 08 48 89 63 10 41 be ff ff ff ff 4c 89 3c 24 48 89 44 24 08 <48> 89 20 4c 89 6c 24 10 eb 21 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 c7 45 00 02
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001]  RSP <ffff88007c2e38c0>
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.160001] CR2: 0000000000000000
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.638780] ---[ end trace cfe04fa841e68257 ]---
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.844056] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   14.948247] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   18.305021] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
May  3 20:20:45 ledzep3 kernel: [   18.308221] tg3 0000:03:00.0 eth1: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX'
    May
```

Comment: Persevered for a few more hours then and finally conceded defeat. Loaded 16.04LTS with kernel 4 and all's well again. Normal service has been restored. Yet to tweak to see if the T2 channels are availabel now but optimistic since the the logs are so positive !!

Answer (score 0):

Persevered for a few more hours then and finally conceded defeat. Binned off 14.04 and 3.16 kernel, loaded 16.04LTS with kernel 4 on reformatted SSD and all's well again. Normal service has been restored.

Yet to tweak to see if the T2 channels are availabel now but optimistic since the the logs are so positive !!